# How add to attributes to model

Tags: python, django

I have a model where I want to do some procesing and append an attribute before sending it off as json. I've tried to just modify as such: 
`client = Client.objects.all()` and then
`client.newAttribute`
but that didn't work as it wasn't passed in my json with: 
`return json.dumps(clients,  cls=ExtendedEncoder)` 
where `clients` is a list of `client` and `ExtendedEncoder` is

```
class ExtendedEncoder(DjangoJSONEncoder):
    def default(self, o):
        if isinstance(o, Model):
            return model_to_dict(o)
        return super().default(o)
```

I am currently trying something new where my model is

```
class Client(models.Model):
    my_id = models.CharField(max_length=500, unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    last_update = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    rating = models.DecimalField(max_digits=3, decimal_places=1, null=True, blank=True)
    friend_1 = models.ForeignKey(
        "self",
        related_name="friend_1a",
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        to_field="my_id",
        null=True,
        blank=True,
    )
    friend_2 = models.ForeignKey(
        "self",
        related_name="friend_2a",
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        to_field="my_id",
        null=True,
        blank=True,
    )

    def _get_time_since_last_update(self):
        today = date.today()
        if self.last_update is None:
            self.last_update = today
        return str((today - self.last_update).days)


    time_since_last_update = property(_get_time_since_last_update)
```

but this still isn't getting returned in my json.

Comment: Use a serializer to convert models to json

Comment: isn't that what i'm doing? sorry if i'm naive.

Comment: Check this https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/

Comment: Hey thanks! This is exactly what I need and will also solve another problem I have!